# Is there any difference between mod_rewrite's HTTP:Host and HTTP_HOST variables?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Is there any difference (subtle or otherwise) between the following rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www.mysite.co.uk$
```

In the second example I access the host name by specifying the HTTP header name: `Host`.

On the surface they both appear to behave exactly the same and if I turn up [rewrite logging to `3`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLogLevel) the log file shows identical activity.

Is `%{HTTP_HOST}` just a synonym for `%{HTTP:Host}`? For example, is `%{HTTP_HOST}` already populated/bound early whilst `%{HTTP:Host}` might incur a lookup penalty ?

Answer (score 0):

They are synonyms. See quotes from [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) below:

About server variables like `HTTP_HOST`:

```
These variables all correspond to the similarly named HTTP MIME-headers,
C variables of the Apache server or struct tm fields of the Unix system.
Most are documented elsewhere in the Manual or in the CGI specification.
```

About `HTTP:variable`:

```
%{HTTP:header}, where header can be any HTTP MIME-header name, can always
be used to obtain the value of a header sent in the HTTP request.
```